# third party content app document for app store

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, documentation

i send multi time app for review in app store but not accept and it's need third party Document, but i don't find anything about it. there isn't any sample or example
my app work with my site api and get data from my site

**the review result :**

> The inclusion of third party content within the application, whether
>   retrieved from the internet by the application or embedded in the
>   application, is subject to the terms of the iOS Developer Program
>   License Agreement. You must warrant that your application does not
>   infringe the rights of a third party by providing documentary evidence
>   that you have the rights to use this content.
>
> Acceptable documentation includes a copy of your contract with the
>   copyright holder to your company, detailing your authorization.

please if have any idea or experiment about that , help me
Thanks

**Update (22/2/2019)**
i send a doc that include the website owner signed that i have right to use api and publish this app but it's rejected again .

**the new answer of app store reviewer :**

> Thank you for the message. After review of the documentation, we are
>   requesting further documentation demonstrating your right to use the
>   third-party content. Documentation must prove the third party content
>   owners have agreed to distribute their work through your platform.
>   Furthermore, please be sure to include dates, rights holders' names,
>   your company's name, and relevant signatures.

Answer (score 3):

## Copyright Contract

> You must warrant that your application does not infringe the rights of a third party by providing documentary evidence that you have the rights to use this content.

Apple is asking for proof that you have the *right* to use the Third Party Content in your app.

You can do this by providing the requested [contract with the copyright holder](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=contract+with+the+copyright+holder). A contract can come in many forms depending on the laws and countries involved. Apple does not provide examples because of this diversity.

Ultimately, Apple needs to know you accept responsibility and have the legal right to distribute other's work through your app.

- What content do you include or make accessible in your app?
- Do you *really* have the right to republish it?

Apple needs you to **prove** this.