# App store require Documents for authorized to distribute the content

Tags: ios-appstore

i publish my application on app store but it's not accepted in several time and the reviewer request for the document for authorized to distribute the content
but i don't know how to document ?

**the app store reviewer Answer :**

> Thank you for your message. Please respond with documentation attached, using the upload feature, evidencing that Jenyar has been authorized to distribute the content owned by the artists. Once Legal has reviewed your documentation and confirms its validity, we will proceed with your application review.

please if anybody know about this guide me
Thanks

Comment: Judging by your last question on this topic, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/351601/third-party-content-app-document-for-app-store I think it's probably time to talk to a lawyer.

Comment: Getting submissions from the 3rd parties that are acceptable to prove their acceptance of the conditions will probably be a better use of your time instead of repeating the same question.